# How do I render the entity of a tweet object in the view?

Tags: arrays, twitter, hash, rendering

When displaying a Tweet object in the view, "tweet.urls" gives me the following:

```
[#<Twitter::Entity::URI:0x007fb48b01bb38 @attrs={:url=>"https://electrek.co/2016/11/22/elon-musk-right-wing-trump-propaganda-campaign-against-tesla-spacex/", :expanded_url=>"https://electrek.co/2016/11/22/elon-musk-right-wing-trump-propaganda-campaign-against-tesla-spacex/", :display_url=>"electrek.co/2016/11/22/elo…", :indices=>[113, 136]}>]
```

But I can't figure out how to extract the :url and display only that in the view.

Comment: nevermind...think I got it.  <%= tweet.urls[0]["url"] %>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  <%= tweet.urls[0]["url"] %>